# My VBA code to separate a filter in different worksheets is creating empty worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub um_separatabelanosfiltros()
Dim r As Integer, brand As String, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter
r = 1
Do
    r = r + 1
    brand = ws.Range("A" & r).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets(brand) Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=brand
        ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Sheets.Add.Name = brand
        Sheets(brand).Paste
        ws.ShowAllData
    End If
Loop While ws.Range("A" & r + 1).Value <> ""
End Sub
```

With this code i can separate a worksheet by the filters in the A1 cell, but i tried to use it in a different dataset and it kept creating empty worksheets, any sugestion and or help?

Iv tried alot of thing and my conclusion is that some how the data is screwing it up, i just dont know how it can do that or how to fix it

Comment: Are the values in ColA unique?  If not then you'd be copy/pasting the same rows over and over?   If they are unique then you don't need to use AutoFilter.

Comment: No, i have a bunch of the same values, they are names, like james, amy, josh... imagine 100 rows for each name, and a buch of data for each name, like objects that each one of them has, jeans, cap, celphone... and i want to separate the work sheets, so i can save them separatly and send them via email only their items. i hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a ready list of unique items in the column you want to split on, you can do it without autofilter:

```vb
Sub um_separatabelanosfiltros()
    
    Dim brand As String, wsData As Worksheet, wsBrand As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook, cBrand As Range
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = ActiveSheet
    
    Set cBrand = wsData.Range("A2")   'first brand
    
    Do While Len(cBrand.Value) > 0
        
        brand = cBrand.Value
        
        Set wsBrand = Nothing  'clear sheet reference
        On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if no sheet match
        Set wsBrand = wb.Worksheets(brand)
        On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors ASAP
        
        If wsBrand Is Nothing Then  'need to create a new sheet?
            Set wsBrand = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            wsBrand.name = brand
            wsData.Rows(1).Copy wsBrand.Range("A1") 'copy headers
        End If
        
        cBrand.EntireRow.Copy wsBrand.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Set cBrand = cBrand.Offset(1) 'Next row of data
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code returned an error that i can fix, the true problem was that i was using the full name of the person, excel dont like to create worksheets with names that exceed 31 caracters. my code worked fine now too. Thx for the help, your code woked just fine, the one i stole from else where is a bit faster tho haha